# I can't change a component's property values in react-native IOS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I can't change a component's property values in react-native IOS, android I managed to change a value or overwrite it, in IOS I can't.

```
  React.Children.forEach(children, (child: any) => {
    if (child.props) {
      Object.entries(child.props).map(([key, value]) => {
        if (value ===  ERROR  [TypeError: onPress is not a function. (In 'onPress(event)', 'onPress' is "sd:context:action")]) {
          child.props[key] = context.setShow;
        }
      });
    }
  });


 ERROR  [TypeError: onPress is not a function. (In 'onPress(event)', 'onPress' is "sd:context:action")]

change the property

change value "sd:context:action" for functions setShow
```